# Вызов функции по изменению переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Есть переменная которая связана с полем (с использованием vue). Как вызвать функцию каждый раз когда переменная изменяется?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для наблюдения у Vue есть отличные методы; [watch](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), например:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    input: '',
    watchInput: '',
  },
  watch: {
    input: function () {
      this.watchInput = `New watchInput value: ${Math.random()}!`;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
  <input type='text' v-model='input' />
  <div>{{ watchInput }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```js
methods: {
  changeInput: function () {
    console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

```html
<input @change="changeInput()" v-model="model">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать обернуть в computed, метод будет вызываться, когда переменная varName изменится

```
data() {
  return {
    dataName: null
  }
},
computed: {
  varName() {
    this.yourMethod();
    return this.dataName;
  }
},
methods: {
  yourMethod() {
  ...
  }
}
```